# 101 Manage_pages permission has been revoked for the app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks

I am trying to create test lead for a subscribed page but it gives me this error,

> 101   Manage_pages permission has been revoked for the app

I have already approved these permissions for app

1. pages_manage_metadata
2. pages_read_engagement
3. pages_show_list
4. pages_manage_ads
5. leads_retrieval

Anyone knows what's wrong?

Thank you..

Comment: Hey @Akshay, did you find a solution for this?